# SES Console AWS Sending Email is not Working for Raw Message

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am wondering if anyone can help me why I cannot send email using Raw Message in SES Console in AWS. But using the Formatted message its working. All the necessary configs are already set up. What do I need to set. Here are the setup i did.

1. Setup the Policy in the IAM. Add policy to the the created group [AmazonSESFullAccess].
2. Verified the Email [email address status is verified]
3. Send Email in the SES Console using the Raw Message is not working. [but using the Formatted Message it sends the email successfully]

Any idea please..... :-)

Comment: Please, paste the raw message here.

Comment: Hi @sailesh, what message are you refering to? The one I inputed in the email or the error message. Actually, i inputed the email from and to email address which already verified. And the email body.   the button is actually clickable and successfully sent. But if I check the inbox. There is no actual email sent.

Comment: Both, if possible. Just edit your question by pasting both

Comment: @sailesh - There is no error. it was successfully sending the message. But when I check my email. There is no message received. But if i try using the Formatted email it's working properly. (The first radio button in the email Composer). i am referring the SES Console, i just want to test the raw message Because I am gonna use it for my customized java email sending

Comment: I am not yet capable in pasting the screenshot here.

Comment: Copy and paste the raw message here

Comment: How can I get It? I just used the normal email interface of the SES Console by clicking the Send Test Email. Then selecting the Raw.  I am not yet so familiar with SES.

Answer (score 0):

This is already solved by moving to a different region. I was using the Oregon before and moved it N. Virginia. And in the java code I added the code

Region REGION = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1); 
         amazonSimpleEmailService.setRegion(REGION);